# Flutter CustomPainter Pan and Zoom

Tags: flutter

I have created a family tree widget via CustomPainter. How do I implement pan and zoom because parts of it overflowed.

I have tried GestureDetector and Translating the points via onPanUpdate but it is resetting to the current offset.

```dart
onPanUpdate: (d) {
          RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
          Offset point = box.globalToLocal(d.globalPosition);
          point = point.translate(0.0, AppBar().preferredSize.height);


           setState(() {
             _offset = point;
           });

          // print(point);
        },

// this is from CustomPainter

canvas.translate(offset.dx, offset.dy);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/klaszlo8207/0df97fb3ba7484e20b0061076f3be842

Here is my gist for this, this is a custom **GestureDetector** that can Scale and Pan

Comment: Hello. Can you give full example? There is not CustomPainter or canvas

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried InteractiveViewer? It works pretty well with CustomPainter.

Here a sample to zoom a container:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        minScale: 0.1,
        maxScale: 1.6,
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: <Color>[Colors.orange, Colors.red],
              stops: <double>[0.0, 1.0],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34669677)